# How to get and parse data from geocode farm

Tags: php

I am trying to get my website to get the json from the geocode farm api. I know how to contstruct the address where the api is but I don't know how to get the data back and parse and then display it in a javascript alert.

If you can help me do that, I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Getting useful data out of the JSON response

Once you have a working URL that dumps the required JSON data, it's very easy. PHP offers built-in functions for processing and dealing with JSON data. In this case, you want to decode the JSON data into a usable format, such as an array or object.

## Converting the JSON response to an array

To get it into an array, you can simply do:

```
$arr = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://example.com/foo.json'), 1);
```

## Knowing the structure of the array

Now in order to work with the array, you will have to know how it is structured. For that purpose, you can use the debugging function `print_r()`:

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r($arr, 1) . '</pre>';
```

## Traversing the array to extract information

Once you know the structure of the JSON data, you can traverse it using a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    // Do more stuff with $value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a request with PHP, for example using `file_get_contents()` and then echo the result into JavaScript. You can then use JavaScript to extract the information you need and generate an alert.

Simplified example:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://api-url...';
$response = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($response, true);
$coordinates = $data['geocoding_results']['COORDINATES'];
?>
<script>
var coordinates = <?php echo json_encode($coordinates); ?>;
alert(coordinates.latitude + '; coordinates.longitude);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I then concatenate textbox input to the url variable?